# Adding preview option in cq:dialog?

Tags: aem

Is it possible to add a session in cq:dialog which renders whatever data is supplied in the fields and previews it out in real time. In the simplest of scenarios, I need to add two numbers and when I enter both the numbers the cq:dialog should preview it's output as 4. There should be two sessions in the the cq:dialog, like two columns, the left one to enter value to the fields and the right to display the rendered output. How to achieve this? Is it possible to?

Comment: I think you need to write down a clientlib JS, which calls a service with the values entered on those fields and at server side get the path and update the calculated value in the targeted field. YOU NEED TO ADD THIS TO YOUR DIALOG AS extraClientlibs.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of "event handlers". Adobe docs has a simple example using JQuery that you can customize for your requirement.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-events.html